# Using mapply over a matrix when the function makes use of elemets' location in the matrix

Tags: r, matrix, mapply

I want to use `mapply` to apply `fun` to all elements of a matrix. I'm not sure how to use `mapply` when the function to be applied makes use of each elements' location in the matrix.

```
    fun <- function(theta, mat, i, j){
    sum_nearby <- function(mat,i,j,dist){
        if (j - dist < 1) mat[i, j + dist] 
        else if (j + dist > ncol(mat)) mat[i, j - dist]
        else mat[i, j - dist] + mat[i, j + dist]
    }
        g0  <- -2*mat[i,j]
        g1  <- g0*sum_nearby(mat,i,j,1)

        -log1p(exp(theta %*% c(g0, g1)))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mapply` over the row and column indices like this where `fun` is the function defined in the question.  The result is a numeric vector `v`:

```
# test inputs
theta <- 1:2
mat <- as.matrix(BOD)

v <- mapply(fun, row(mat), col(mat), MoreArgs = list(theta = theta, mat = mat))
```

Then it can be summed like this `sum(v)` or reshaped into a matrix with the same dimensions as `mat` like this: `replace(mat, TRUE, v)` or `array(v, dim(mat))` or `matrix(v, nrow(mat))` or `0*mat+v`

**Note:** Alternatives would be to use `outer` returning a matrix having the same dimensions as `mat`:

```
outer(1:nrow(mat), 1:ncol(mat), Vectorize(function(i, j) fun(theta, mat, i, j)))
```

or `apply` returning a vector as in `mapply` solution above:

```
apply(cbind(c(row(mat)), c(col(mat))), 1, function(ix) fun(theta, mat, ix[1], ix[2]))
```